# TestBed.overrideProvider now overriding the providers

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-test, testbed

I have configured the testing module in the first `beforeEach` block. Here's the code:

```
 beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        MaterialModule,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
      ],
      declarations: [AddOrEditAvtComponent],
      providers: [
        TypesAvtService,
        UserService,
        {
          provide: MatDialogRef,
          useClass: MatDialogRefMock,
        },
        {
          provide: MAT_DIALOG_DATA,
          useValue: {},
        },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));
```

I want to override the `MAT_DIALOG_DATA` with some different data, for that I am using `TestBed.overrideProvider` but, it still uses the initial value i.e. `{}`.

Here's the other piece of code:

```
it(`should display the Signatory value in the text box`, () => {
  TestBed.overrideProvider(MAT_DIALOG_DATA, {
    useValue: {
      title: 'Edit Signaroty',
      typesData: {
        avtName: 'Agent',
      },
      category: 'Signatory',
    },
  });

  TestBed.compileComponents();
  matDialogRef = TestBed.get(MatDialogRef);
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddOrEditAvtComponent);

  fixture.detectChanges();
  const inputEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input'))
    .nativeElement;

  expect(inputEl.value).toBe('Agent');
});
```

Here's the constructor that I want to test:

```
constructor(
    private readonly _typeAvt: TypesAvtService,
    private readonly _user: UserService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddOrEditAvtComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA)
    public data: { title: string; typesData: TypeAvt; category: AvtType },
  ) {
    this.avtData = this.data.typesData;
    this.pageTitle = this.data.title;
    this.category = this.data.category;

    this.avtName = new FormControl(this.avtData ? this.avtData.avtName : '', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(/\S/), // anything except all whitespace
      avtExists(this._typeAvt, this.avtData, this.category),
    ]);

    this.addOrEditForm = new FormGroup({
      typeName: this.avtName,
    });
  }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the completed test case?

Comment: @yurzui I updated the question